# Trying to understand Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a few arrays

```
var item = [{
    name : "somename",
    type1 : "wood",
    location : "some location",
    desc : "some description"
}, {
    name : "somename",
    type1 : "metal",
    location : "somelocation",
    desc : "some description"
}];
```

and

```
var shopState = 0;
var hasInv = [];
var pickedItem = [];
```

I assume I have 2 empty arrays with that last one.  Later on I attempt to make use of these in a function.

```
function shop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        if (item[i].location == "some location") {
            //get all items at some location
            hasInv[i] = item[i];
        }
    }
    if (shopState == 1) {
        var d = 1;
        for (var i = 1; i < hasInv.length; i++) {
            if (hasInv[i].type1 == 'wood') {
                //get all wood items at some location 
                pickedItem[d] = hasInv[i];
                d++;
                console.log(pickedItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That last bit with `pickedItem` returned undefined unless I declare `pickedItem = [];` in `shopState` when I thought I already declared it at the start of the file.  It works when I do but I'm trying to understand why it does not if i don't.

Comment: You should use `var d`

Comment: Why, in your second `for` loop are you starting from `1`? With the code you've given, it won't ever run the body of the loop (because `hasInv` will only have one item at index `0`

Comment: What else are you doing to `pickedItem`? Can you please show us the whole file as one, including the call to `shop`?

Comment: What do you mean by "unless I declare `pickedItem = [];` in `shopState`"? `shopState()` isn't a function. Did you mean `shop`?

Comment: And you also have `hasInv[i].type`, whereas your object's property is `type1`

Comment: If you fix the problem with the index and with the property name, it works just fine. But even without those, there is no problem with `pickedItem` being undefined

Comment: I corrected the code in question. `var d` and `type1` one are correct, i just typo'd when transfering it to here.  What i mean by "unless i delcare `pickedItem = [];` in shopState is that if its not declared after `var d = 1;` it comes back undefined.

Comment: *"unless i delcare pickedItem = []; in shopState is that if its not declared after var d = 1; it comes back undefined"* - no it doesn't. Please post code that actually demonstrates the problem you are having because what you have in the question does not reproduce the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions: Is your conditional for `shopState` passing? I don't see where you increment shopState. Also is there a reason you are setting to indexes directly instead of using .push or .unshift? Maybe for time complexity concerns? I'm assuming the purpose of the function is to iterate through store locations to find matching locations and then find all items of a certain type at that location? Is that correct? If that is true here is the solution:

```
function shop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        if (item[i].location == "some location") {
            //get all items at some location
            hasInv.push(item[i]);
            //You weren't increment shopState
            shopState++;
        }
    }
    if (shopState == 1) {
    //conditional now passes
    //there is no need to set a additional index variable.
        for (var i = 0; i < hasInv.length; i++) {
            if (hasInv[i].type1 == 'wood') {
                //get all wood items at some location
                pickedItem.push(hasInv[i]);
                console.log(pickedItem);
            }
        }
    }
}

shop()
```

Also note that your conditional makes it so you will only locate one item with the wood type. To change this so that your comment is true and you are collecting all items simply change your conditional to:

```
if(shopState >= 1)
```

As well you are only checking one location because you have combined the words some and location in the second object of your items array.